# SQLite Multi-Column Unique Constraint Allows Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm porting a MySQL database to SQLite, and having trouble with SQLite allowing duplicate values.

```
CREATE TABLE altnames (
    Prime     CHAR (20),
    Alternate CHAR (20),
    UNIQUE ( Prime, Alternate )
);

CREATE INDEX prime     ON altnames ( Prime     );
CREATE INDEX alternate ON altnames ( Alternate );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Combined ON altnames (
    Prime,
    Alternate
);
```

I'm using HeidiSQL to export to CSV, and importing from there using SQLiteStudio. It will catch duplicates of values I enter manually, but once I import the data from the MySQL table, it won't catch dupes of those values.

The purpose of the table is to link various forms of names. Some sample data:

```
"Al","Alan"
"Al","Albert"
"Al","Alfred"
"Al","Allan"
"Al","Allen"
"Al","Alvin"
"Alan","Al"
"Alan","Allan"
"Alan","Allen"
"Albert","Al"
"Albert","Bert"
"Albert","Bertie"
"Alfred","Al"
"Alfred","Fred"
"Alfred","Freddie"
"Alfred","Freddy"
"Allan","Al"
"Allan","Alan"
"Allan","Allen"
"Allen","Al"
"Allen","Alan"
"Allen","Allan"
```

If I add these items through the SQLiteStudio interface or programatically, the constraint is triggered, but if I import them, inserts on these values will not trigger it. For example, `insert into altnames values ('Al', 'Alan')` will succeed, giving me two rows with those values.

EDIT:

I found some rather strange behavior. According to [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), the default behavior for `ON CONFLICT` is `ABORT`, which is supposed to generate a `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT` error and rollback the conflicting data. I found that, if I import the data from CSV file, it does the rollback, but does not generate the error. If I include an `ON CONFLICT` clause, it does the rollback and generates an error. **However**, rather than CSV, if I export the data as SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `altnames` (`Prime`, `Alternate`) VALUES
  ('Al', 'Alan'),
  ('Al', 'Albert'),
  ('Al', 'Alfred'),
  ('Al', 'Allan'),
  ......
```

and import that way...then I get the documented behavior, regardless of whether I specify `ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: You don't need the last index; the UNIQUE constraint already creates an internal one. Anyway, show an example.

Comment: @CL. But won't the index speed up constraint checking? Or is it automatically indexed if there's a `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: The UNIQUE constraint already creates an internal index. Show an example of the data that fails.

Comment: @CL. That's good to know. Just out of curiosity, does specifying a `UNIQUE` constraint and also creating a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the same column create two indices, or does it get optimized out?

Comment: That would create two indices, which doubles the cost of maintaining it when the table data changes.

Comment: Show the output of `SELECT * FROM altnames WHERE Prime = 'Al' AND Alternate = 'Alan';` after the double insert.

Comment: @CL. OK, I see what you're getting at -- it's silently rolling back the data. But see my edit above. My main issue was that it was not generating an error, but I can take care of that by either including an `ON CONFLICT` clause, or importing the data as SQL. Weird. Anyway, thanks for your help, and the info on indices.

Comment: When I try to import a duplicate, I get `import.csv:1: INSERT failed: UNIQUE constraint failed: altnames.Prime, altnames.Alternate`. You still have not provided an example of the actual import data.

Comment: @CL.I copied and pasted some data from the CSV file - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Works for me with that CSV data and `sqlite3`. Apparently, SQLite Studio is buggy.

Comment: @CL. I was also failing to get an error when performing the insert programatically through System.Data.SQLite. I don't know. Anyway, it's handled now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sqlite3 command-line tool to open the database file and do:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE import(prime, alternate);
.sep ','
.import tabledata.csv import
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO altnames SELECT * FROM import;
```